# Adding annotation to MapView inside collection view cell using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, annotations, mapkit, uicollectionviewcell

I'm stuck with this issue and not sure where to start from.

I have added a map view inside a `collectionviewcell` and based on the **longitudes and latitudes data coming from JSON** i'm adding pins to the map. I think i'm able to add pins to the map but when i run the app on the simulator and start to scroll through the list, the number of pins seem to get doubled or tripled depending on the array size.

Here is my `collectionviewcell:`

```
func configureCell(bar: Bars) {

        addressDescLbl.text = bar.address
        barNameLbl.text = bar.name
        fb_url = bar.fb
        moreInfo_url = bar.url

        let location = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: bar.latitude, longitude: bar.longitude)
        centerMapOnLOcation(location, bar: bar)

    }

    func centerMapOnLOcation(location: CLLocationCoordinate2D, bar: Bars){
        let span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.5, 0.5)
        let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: location, span: span)
        self.barsMapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
        let artwork = Artwork(title: bar.name, locationName: bar.address, discipline: "scul", coordinate: location)
        self.barsMapView.addAnnotation(artwork)
    }
```

Here is my `cellForItemAtIndexPath:`

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        if let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("BarsVC", forIndexPath: indexPath) as? BarsCell {
            let currentBar: Bars!
            if inSearchMode == true {
                currentBar = filteredBars[indexPath.row]
            }
            else {
                currentBar = bar[indexPath.row]
            }
            cell.configureCell(currentBar)
            return cell
        }


            return UICollectionViewCell()

    }
```

Here is my Artwork class:

```
class Artwork: NSObject, MKAnnotation {

    let title: String?
    let locationName:String
    let discipline:String
    let coordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2D

    init(title: String, locationName: String, discipline: String, coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
        self.title = title
        self.locationName = locationName
        self.discipline = discipline
        self.coordinate = coordinate

        super.init()
    }

    var subtitle: String? {
        return locationName
    }
```

[Initially the number of pins was 1 but as i scroll and come back to this cell, it gets doubled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ifJfz.png)

Any suggestions or thoughts?

Comment: Before you go ahead with this implementation I would like to recommend that you should rethink about putting multiple mapView on screen. Every instance of MapView takes whole lot of memory and it will bite you once you add more. I would recommend using MKMapSnapshotter. Here is documentation link https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapSnapshotter_class/

Comment: thanks @Sumit. I'll definitely look into this.